# Magento2, where can I see the file equivalent to 2-columns-left.phtml as in magento1

Tags: magento2, layout, sidebar

In magento one, I could easily add class to below structure in `2-columns-left.phtml`, how can I do the same in magento2?

```
<div class="col-main mycustomclass">
                    ....
</div>
<div class="col-left sidebar mycustomclass"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
```

Update (what we have in magento2):

How can I add class to `<container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">` in `2columns-left.xml`

```
<update handle="1column"/>
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main col-sm-3 col-md-3" after="main">
        <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
    </container>
    <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
        <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, pls check the update part, I couldn't figure out how to add class to the class="column main"